# Logback is truncating instead of appending to log file

Tags: java, logback

We have a straightforward Logback configuration copied below. My expectation is that the application would continue to write (i.e. append) to the log file on startup. However, when we restart the application, the existing file is discarded and the logger creates a new file. My understanding is that the FileAppender appends to the log file by default. Even adding the "true" does not make a difference. Am I missing something?

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <append>true</append>
    <File>${logDir}/${filename}.log</File>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this help? http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html

Comment: Thanks vikingsteve - I do not want to implement a time or size based rolling policy. Simply need to append to the file instead of truncating and writing to the file on startup. I don't see anything in the RollingFileAppender that I can use without writing my own appender.

Answer (score 0):

Luhar,

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer for this as I see that the question was asked quite a while back. But I recently did some work with logback and stumbled upon this unanswered question. What you were trying to do looked pretty straightforward, so I thought I'd give it a whirl and see what's going on.

Using the following logback configuration and the accompanying code I was able to append to the log file just fine.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <File>test.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
                %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Simple Java class using the configuration above:

```
public class App {

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SimpleTest");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("This is an INFO statement");
        logger.warn("This is a WARN statement");
        logger.error("This is an ERROR statement");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);     
            // make sure the AsyncAppender queue is flushed
            // before program exits
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The following is my log file after 3 runs of the program.

20141222-22:32:10.391 [main] INFO  SimpleTest -
                This is an INFO statement

20141222-22:32:10.393 [main] WARN  SimpleTest -
                This is a WARN statement

20141222-22:32:10.393 [main] ERROR SimpleTest -
                This is an ERROR statement

20141222-22:32:18.558 [main] INFO  SimpleTest -
                This is an INFO statement

20141222-22:32:18.560 [main] WARN  SimpleTest -
                This is a WARN statement

20141222-22:32:18.560 [main] ERROR SimpleTest -
                This is an ERROR statement

20141222-22:32:23.192 [main] INFO  SimpleTest -
                This is an INFO statement

20141222-22:32:23.194 [main] WARN  SimpleTest -
                This is a WARN statement

20141222-22:32:23.194 [main] ERROR SimpleTest -
                This is an ERROR statement

So I think the logback configuration is working correctly. Hope this helps!